# Is it correct to use the indefinite article before the name of dances?

Tags: articles

Which article: *a* or *the* is it the most natural to use in the following sentence?

> Let's dance **a**/**the** waltz at our wedding.

Are both pissible? If so, then is there a difference in meaning or it is just a matter of prefference?

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dance+a+waltz%2Cdance+the+waltz&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdance%20a%20waltz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdance%20the%20waltz%3B%2Cc0), both articles are about equally common. I don't have any particular preference myself, and it's hard to think of a context where they might have different *meanings*.

Comment: ...belay that! I'd much prefer the definite article in something like *They danced **the** waltz all night long.* That's because *to dance **a** waltz* implies ***a single turn on the dance floor***, which wouldn't be likely to last all night long unless it was in the context of some kind of "endurance dancing" for a charity event or similar.

Comment: _The_ waltz is the name of the style of dance. _A_ waltz is a single dance, as @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica says, or a piece of music to dance the waltz to.

Comment: @KateBunting: I was careful to say ***implies*** rather than ***is*** or ***means***. But yeah - in the context of *learners*, I'd say our distinction is certainly "close enough".

Comment: So if I say "let's dance a waltz" that would mean that I would like dance the waltz for the duration of a song to which the waltz is danced, am I right?

Comment: Yes - or, more likely, a piece of instrumental music